# How to control the web components without the use of Selenium or any other third party libraries?

Tags: python, go, jvm

I want to automate the webpage interactions without the use of Selenium web drivers. I didn't find the solution yet, how can I do it without the help of any third party libraries.

Is it possible to do with only built-in features of any language. Is it possible using Golang, Python or Java?

Thanks

Comment: You can write your own client for web driver protocol but it is not recommend

Comment: in golang, if that is what you want, you can check for https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp

Comment: Can you help me understand why you don’t want to use Selenium? Is it WebDriver that you find objectionable? If you don’t care about cross-browser execution, any of the Chromium Debig Protocol solutions might provide an option. If cross-browser execution is important, what is your resistance to using W3C web standards like WebDriver (which is akin to supporting the monoculture of IE6 in the 90s or Chrome today)?